# How I get my friendly monsters to do my work for me?

Tags: rune-factory-4

There is an option to ask monsters in your barn to do work for you in the fields and stuff, but every time I ask my monsters, I get a notice saying they don't like me enough to do it.

How do I get them to do the work?

Answer (score 2):

You have to get their friendship level to 4.  The simple (albeit tedious) way to do this is brush them and talk to them every day.  That ensures they're in no danger.  That will take some time to get them to the required level of friendship.  You can also take them adventuring with you.  They will get little bits of friendship for helping you, and that has no friendship requirement, so you can get them, and take them adventuring with you right away.

After you get them to the correct point, you can talk to them, choose "Assign Field Chores", and then choose Left, Middle, or Right.  By doing so, they'll water their assigned section, leaving the harvesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to raise their friendship level to at least 3 or 4 I think. You can brush them and take them adventuring with you to raise their level. They can also fight for you and leveling them up is easy. Just go with them monster slashing. Don't forget to feed them fodder or food though. My fairy is now level 60 and has an a attack power of 578 right now. And you can have more than 1 monster aiding you in battle so that makes dungeons less of a pain. Hope that helped. :)